# Ruby -> RestClient::Resource -> post -> arguments

Tags: ruby, rest, post

I do constructed RestClient wrapper

```
require 'json'
require 'rest_client'

$url_common_part = 'http://host:port/cgi-bin/cgi_script'

class Grabber
    def initialize
        @site = RestClient::Resource.new($url_common_part)
    end
    def post ( path, params )
        site_and_path = @site["#{path}"]
        payload = params.to_json
        puts "\n", payload
        response = site_and_path.post (
            payload,
            headers = {
                'MY-HEADER' => 'MY-VALUE',
                'content_type' => 'json',
                'accept' => 'json'
            }
        )
        return response
    end
end
```

and get works well, but post gives error `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)`

*May anybody suggest what am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your call to post:

```
response = site_and_path.post (
            payload,
            headers = {
                'MY-HEADER' => 'MY-VALUE',
                'content_type' => 'json',
                'accept' => 'json'
            }
        )
```

You are doing an assignment to `headers` when the second parameter is a hash (which can include headers):

```
response = site_and_path.post (
            payload,
            headers: {
                'MY-HEADER' => 'MY-VALUE',
                'content_type' => 'json',
                'accept' => 'json'
            }
        )
```

Comment: Hi [Chris](http://stackoverflow.com/users/765357/chris), have tried your advice, and got `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /home/kacper/…/Grabber.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)`

KAcper